# I see the classes changing in the browser console but no visual change in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just for practice sake, I am trying to change the background color of a div if you hover your mouse over it, and restore it back when you hover out. And if you click the div, I change its background color yet again to something different and make it editable. When you click outside, I restore things back to normal and make the div read-only again.

Up until an hour ago, my code worked fine on both counts -- added and removed the required classes to the target element(s), *and* I could see the visual change to the elements.

Suddenly, then, the visual changes stopped happening even though I see the CSS classes being correctly added and removed on the proper events. In other words, the background color of `#theDiv` does not change when I hover in and out of it and when I click into it and out of it.

My code is at the git repository here in a file named [contentEditable.html](https://github.com/Sathyaish/Practice/blob/master/HTML5/contentEditable.html).

When it stopped working, I made another file [here named temp.html](https://github.com/Sathyaish/Practice/blob/master/HTML5/temp.html) to isolate the changes I was trying to make and they work correctly in temp.html. They just stopped working all of a sudden in contentEditable.html.

Although the code is already linked to above in my git repo, I am reproducing it here as well for your convenience.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var theDiv = $("#theDiv");
  var isBeingEdited = false;

  theDiv.on("mouseover", null, true, makeAppearEditable);
  theDiv.on("mouseout", null, false, makeAppearEditable);

  theDiv.on("click dblclick", null, true, makeEditable);
  theDiv.on("blur", null, false, makeEditable);

  function makeAppearEditable(event) {

    console.log(event.target + ": " + event.type);
    var targetElement = $(event.target);

    if (isBeingEdited) {
      return false;
    }

    if (event.data) {
      targetElement.addClass("canBeEdited");
    } else {
      targetElement.removeClass("canBeEdited");
    }
  };

  function makeEditable(event) {

    console.log(event.target + ": " + event.type);

    var targetElement = $(event.target);

    isBeingEdited = event.data;
    targetElement.attr("contenteditable", event.data);

    if (event.data) {
      targetElement.addClass("editable");
    } else {
      targetElement.removeClass("editable");
    }
  };
});
```

```css
#theDiv {
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 50%;
}

;
.editable {
  background-color: #f2e793;
}

;
.canBeEdited {
  background-color: yellow;
}

;
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div id="theDiv">
  This is some text. When you hover over it, it will change its color to indicate that it can be edited. When you click it or double click it, it again change its color and will become editable. When you stop editing and click outside it, it will become
  non-editable and will change its color back to white.
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: @codemonkeh Yes, I did. I've been tinkering with the code as well for sometime after it was working but can't remember anything significant that I might have changed.

Comment: Remove `;` from CSS and it will work

Comment: What's with the random `;` in your CSS? Remove them and the code works. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `;` from CSS and it will work and update CSS rule

```
; <======== remove it
.canBeEdited.editable {
  background-color: #f2e793;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var theDiv = $("#theDiv");
  var isBeingEdited = false;

  theDiv.on("mouseover", null, true, makeAppearEditable);
  theDiv.on("mouseout", null, false, makeAppearEditable);

  theDiv.on("click dblclick", null, true, makeEditable);
  theDiv.on("blur", null, false, makeEditable);

  function makeAppearEditable(event) {

    console.log(event.target + ": " + event.type);
    var targetElement = $(event.target);

    if (isBeingEdited) {
      return false;
    }

    if (event.data) {
      targetElement.addClass("canBeEdited");
    } else {
      targetElement.removeClass("canBeEdited");
    }
  };

  function makeEditable(event) {
    console.log(event.target + ": " + event.type);
    var targetElement = $(event.target);
    isBeingEdited = event.data;
    targetElement.attr("contenteditable", event.data);
    if (event.data) {
      targetElement.addClass("editable");
    } else {
      targetElement.removeClass("editable");
    }
  };
});
```

```css
#theDiv {
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.canBeEdited.editable {
  background-color: #f2e793;
}

.canBeEdited {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div id="theDiv">
  This is some text. When you hover over it, it will change its color to indicate that it can be edited. When you click it or double click it, it again change its color and will become editable. When you stop editing and click outside it, it will become
  non-editable and will change its color back to white.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. A few minutes before I mark you answer with the green checkie.

Comment: okay, hang on one second. While the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events do work fine, the others don't. That is, when I start editing or click into it, it doesn't change the background color to the other color, and similarly does not restore when I click outside the div.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2, Try with `.editable {
  background-color: #f2e793!important;
}` or `.canBeEdited.editable {
  background-color: #f2e793;
}`

Comment: Okay, I just read about this `!important` rule and it does work but I am now curious as to why my code did what it did and I am asking a new question about that. I have found out that the browser overruled by request to change the background color in the `click` event. I want to know why. So, I am asking a new question.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 As `canBeEdited` is defined later CSS rules are taking precedence. For testing define `editable` after `canBeEdited` then it will work event without `important`

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much.